# Install color profile in juno

Tags: release-juno, color, profile

I just installed Juno and I really like it. However I was unable to find the setting to add an specific color profile. As I remember correctly, there has been an own entry in the system settings in Loki, but I'm unable to find it in Juno. I also installed the gnome-color-manager, but it just lets me view the installed color profiles without the possibility changing them. Is this function hidden somewhere in the settings or do I have to use the terminal or isn't it possible to calibrate the screen in the actual status of Juno?

Answer (score 2):

While i'm also very concerned about color switchboard plugin being gone (i'm a photographer so i make a substantial use of color profiles) i did some digging and found this:

https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-display/issues/5

Seems like Elementary wants to move setting color profiles from "Color" settings to "Display" settings. As a result switchboard-plug-gcc-color package is completely gone from Juno repos. So is this transition a bug or work in progress?